# iOS 7. Drawing multi-line text

Tags: ios7, draw

How can I draw long text string in rect with tail truncation?
I tried use `drawInRect:withAttributes:` with `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` paragraph style, but it shows text at single line. It draw multi-line text only with `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` and `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping` break modes.

Where is I wrong? Deprecated method `drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:` worked correct.